# Vbs script to check date and extension

Tags: date, vbscript, file-extension

Hi I cant get the below script ive worked on to pickup the extension of the files, Can any help me out by pointing where I have gone wrong?

```
dim fileSystem, folder, file 
dim path
dim count : count = 0
path = "C:\temp" 

Set fileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set folder = fileSystem.GetFolder(path)

for each file in folder.Files     
    if file.DateLastModified > dateadd("h", -24, Now) & File.name = "txt" then 

count = count + 1

end if
Next

if count < 4 then

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strcommand = "eventcreate /T ERROR /ID 666 /L Application /SO BESROffsite /D " & _  
Chr(34) & count & " Files found please check offsite copy " & Chr(34)  
WshShell.Run strcommand
wScript.Quit ( 1001 )

Else

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strcommand = "eventcreate /T Information /ID 666 /L Application /SO BESROffsite /D " & _  
Chr(34) & count & " Files found offsite is working fine " & Chr(34)  
WshShell.Run strcommand
wScript.Quit ( 0 )
End if
```

Comment: I get the information in the event log as it should do but it is not picking up the files with .txt it just says 0 files found

Comment: `File.neme` is spelt wrong, that might do it?

Comment: na that just my typo on here :( ill correct that on here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.name` is the full name including the extension, to test for the extension;

```
if ... fileSystem.getExtensionName(file.name) = "txt" then
```

You also want the logical `And` not the <strike>bitwise</strike> concatenating `&` in their too.

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat :) still quite new at this but slowly getting there.

Comment: @Alex - +1.5 for catching the &; -0.5 for mistaking concatenation for bitwise and.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer is the one you want, but just for reference if you were working just with vbs and a string filename, without the filesystemobject collection you could achieve the same via:

```
Right(strFilename, Len(strFilename) - Instrrev(strFilename, "."))
```

This essentially finds the position of the final "." in the filename, takes this away from the length of your filename, and then gives you however many character's that equals from the right hand side.  This could be amended slightly to use the "Mid" command rather than the "Right" but I don't think it matters too much in a case like this.